# How to install Google Play Service 7.3.0 or above in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am integrating Google Plus Sign In for my app. The only thing is I have everything updated in Android SDK but still when I run my app in Android Emulator, I get a error in Android Studio saying **"Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7327000 but found 6774480"**.
Android Studio doesn't allow me to use older version of Play Services.

I searched different ways to install latest Google Play Service offline (.apk) but it gives incompatibility error when run using "adb install gps.apk".

How is it like even the latest Android OS image has old version of Google Play Service installed and not even a update indicator in Android SDK for these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Murtaza for contributing to this but I found the solution in between all this. I was using Google API image in Emulator where the Google Play Services are already installed.
So we have 2 options of Uninstalling/Reinstalling them, of which NONE worked.

What I did was downloaded the APK from your given link and installed it on the **Emulator without Google API image**. It successfully installs in there and I got the updated Google Play Service installed on the Emulator.

Comment: I was also able to install an apk from apkmirror onto the vanilla emulator image, but actually trying to run an app that uses google play services causes both to crash. Logcat shows this error: "java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10053 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES." Various methods of installing the apk as a system app did not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Use [APK MIRROR](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/), it contains all version of Google Play Services.

P.S. Remember to uninstall already installed version of Google PlayService from the device before installing the new one.

Comment: I did this but it is giving me following error when I execute this command:
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms-6.7.74

Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Comment: try installing using `adb install -r yourapp.apk`

Comment: Tried that even. It says Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Comment: >adb install -r "com.google.android.gms-7.3.29_(186
6531-470)-7329470-minAPI21.apk" but still [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]