# Google Play Services not updating not to 10.0.+ on emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I can't seem to get the latest google play service on any android studio emulator. I'm running android studio 2.2 with google play version 38. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the avd images for nougat(7.0) and marshmallow(6.0). 
when I create a new device check settings->apps->google play services the version number is still (9.8.70)

My nexus 6 phone is running google play service(10.0.84) so I don't understand why the nougat(7.0) and marshmallow(6.0)emulator image should be lower than that.

is anyone having a similar issue or know a workaround this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue. Looks like necessary update for Google Play Services is still in progress. And unfortunately I still can't find a workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Play Service 7.3.0 or above in Android Emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182686/how-to-install-google-play-service-7-3-0-or-above-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

Try to download and install the latest APK for Play [Services](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/) as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38040679/5832311).

Based from Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), try to navigate to settings--> apps in your emulator and then find Google Play Services. Check the version number and use it in you build.gradle.

As described in the [Google Play services overview](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview.html), Google Play delivers service updates for users on Android 2.3 and higher through the Google Play Store app. However, updates might not reach all users immediately, so your app should verify the version available before attempting to perform API transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It was fixed.

I have the same issue. I needed to update 'google services', because 'google maps' isn't working in the emulator.

However when I try to manually change the version of 'google-services' to '10.0.1' it gives me an error, telling me to 'update the repository', which has a faulty link to it.

I'm now working around it with an older version of my app, but 'google maps' is still inactive for me.

Guess, we just have to wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest "Google APIs  System Image" under "Android 7.1.1 API 25)" bucket in your SDK Manager.

If the image does not contain Google Play services 10, wait for update.

---

There's a lot of myth around this so I'll ask anyway:

Did you know you don't have to depend on latest Play services library if you don't use features introduced in that version?

Stick with 9.8.0. Or 9.6.1. Or 9.4.0. It's ok.